# Indexing of grandchildren: routing

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've created a deep parent child relationship using `Spring Data Elasticsearch`:

```
Parent -> child -> grandchild
```

But my `has_parent` queries on grandchild don't work.
As [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html) says,

> we need to add an extra routing parameter, set to the ID of the grandparent, to ensure that all three generations are indexed on the same shard.

How can I add this parameter in Spring Data Elasticsearch?